# phpinfo() not working on mac OS-X Capitan apache2 server

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, php

I am using `OS-X Capitan` and `Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)`. I have below `phpinfo.php` file

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

when I run the command `php phpinfo.php` it will show `phpinfo()` correctly. This is not showing correctly from browser but instead shows the code as below

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I have made following changes to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

1. uncommented below lines

   `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
   LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`
2. Added `MIME Type` inside `<IfModule mime_module>` tag to above `httpd.conf` file

   `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`
3. Made sure that `libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` exists
4. php -v gives below result

`PHP:  parse error in /etc/php.ini on line 107
PHP 5.5.31 (cli) (built: Feb 20 2016 20:33:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies`

5. `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`
6. Restarted apache2 using command

   `sudo apachectl restart`

Still it shows the php code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` when accessed from browser using url `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`

I have even tried enclosing the code above inside `<html><body>` in which case the `browser screen was blank`.

Comment: What is on line `107` of your `/etc/php.ini`?

Comment: line 106 onwards `; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

Comment: That's one line? It should be `;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`. It seems as though your `php.ini` might've lost it's formatting somehow; if you edited it with something that didn't save it correctly that can happen.

Comment: Looks like no change made to `httpd.conf` is being taken as `<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>` is configured to pick index.php when I hit localhost (/var/www/html) however it still shows directory and I have to click `index.php` from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the `directory` defined for the host as below

`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>`

The problem was solved by enabling and configuring virtual host, however I still think there was no absolute need for virtual host for making php work. `Thoughts welcome on this`.

I then realised that I must enable and configure virtual host as well. I followed steps below

1. Uncomment below lines from `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

`LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so`

This will enable to define `virtual hosts` in `apache2`

2. Edit file `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and declare virtual host as below, comment any default virtual host declaration

   `<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
       ServerName myserver
       ServerAlias myserver-pro
       ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myserver-error_log"
       CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myserver-access_log" common
   </VirtualHost>`

know that this file is included by default in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` using line below.

`Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

and `localhost/phpinfo.php` from browser just works awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Was having similar issue, but with Mac OS high Sierra 10.13.4. 
Simply needed to enable php in apache:

```
sudo nvim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

uncomment the following line

```
#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

then restart apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: tried the earlier answer by @veer7 and didn't work... this answer worked for me,  uncomment that line is all I did!

Comment: What should I do if there is no such line exist?

Answer (score 0):

Check if PHP is enabled in php, look at the folder mod-enabled and search for PHP.

Comment: where can I find the folder named "mod-enabled"? There is no result for `sudo find / -name "*mod-enabled*"`

Comment: @veer7 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ , it was mods-enabled, sorry :)

Comment: nope! no such folder `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`. That should come in `Ubuntu` but I am on `mac OS-X`

Comment: @veer7 try to set AllowOverride to All in your <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents"> section.

Comment: `AllowOverride` set to `all` but in vain

Comment: @veer7 Tried making the apache2 web user owner of the documentroot ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `launchctl` to stop all HTTP Services,  and check the Activity Monitor.